# Finding $\max_{0\leq x\leq3} |f'(x)|$, $\max_{0\leq x\leq3} |f''(x)|$, and $\max_{0\leq x\leq3} |f^{(4)}(x)|$ numerically

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, math-software

In an numerical analysis project I need as an intermediate step to calculate the following:
$$\max_{0\leq x\leq3} |f'(x)|,\ \  \max_{0\leq x\leq3} |f''(x)|\ \ \text{and}\ \ \max_{0\leq x\leq3} |f^{(4)}(x)|$$

Where $f(x)=\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos(x^2))))$

I tried using Wolfram Alpha to find the maximum of each function but it says "No global maximum found". I tried using Maxima but I couldn't find the value for those either. Maybe this is because the expression for the derivatives gets very big due to all the nested trig. functions.

How can I numerically find these values? What are some other tools/software that can handle this?

Comment: Try MAPLE (I have 2021.1), it works perfectly: plot(abs(diff(diff(diff(diff(sin(cos(sin(cos(x*x)))), x), x), x), x)), x = 0 .. 3);

Comment: Not really, I just plotted the functions and tried to estime the maximum values. Do you have a way to solve this? @Moo

Comment: I don't :/ @Moo